# Image from URL showes on iphone but not on ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image, ipad

I'm loading image from URL into my App using this method:

```
  if (url != nil)
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        ASLog2Debug(@"");////////
        NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if ( data == nil )
            return;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // WARNING: is the cell still using the same data by this point??
            self.imgApplicationIcon.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
        });
        [data release];
    });

}
```

It works great on iPhone, but when running the same application on iPad I don't see the images.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an active connection to the internet on your iPad?

Comment: what's the ios version for both your ip and ipad? have you log the image size when app running on your ipad?

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint in the code and then examine the values of the variables?

Comment: Internet connection is ok - loaded other data. And Im running the same iPhone version.

Comment: I do not see anything significantly wrong in this piece of code. Is there any variance in displaying the view on the iPad? Does the image appear well on the iPad when you assign some static dummy image to it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be one of those weird cache problems. Those happen with images.
Go to /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and delete all entries of this app. Then compile and run again.